Enable emojis in Org-Mode tags?
By default you can't use emojis in tags when using org-mode. Is there a simple or not so simple way to enable it?
E.g.
+ [ ] Text0 ::tags:
+ [ ] Text1 ::foo:
+ [X] Text2 ::bar:
+ [ ] Text3 ::moretags:


None that I know of: note that you can use Unicode characters that match the [:alnum:] regex class. As the doc states: " For multibyte characters, it
matches characters whose Unicode ‘general-category’ property (*note
Character Properties::) indicates they are alphabetic or decimal
number characters.", but the emojis above are of general category symbol, other.

Try https://github.com/emacsmirror/org-pretty-tags
